# Почему не работает input file при загрузке через ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Проблема в следующем:
Загружаю форму через AJAX, в форме есть поле input[type=file], но при нажатии на поле - не открывается диалоговое окно для выбора файла... При входе на форму на прямую - всё открывается.

В целом выяснил, если добавлять input[type=file] динамически через jQuery - он не работает.

```
$(".clkfile").append('<input name="image" type="file">');
```

Как добиться работоспособности, не теряя при этом функционал подгрузки формы через ajax?

Comment: Вы уверены что проблема именно из-за того что происходит вставка? Сделал пример и в нём у меня всё работает: [jsfiddle.net/cetmhgsz/](https://jsfiddle.net/cetmhgsz/)

Answer (score 0):

Перепроверьте Ваш код.
Сделал как Вы описали - все работает.
Возможно Вы напутали с классами в js.

```
<form class="clkfile">

</form>

<button id="handler_btn" type="button">add file input</button>
```

```
$('#handler_btn').on('click', function() {

    $('.clkfile').append('<input name="image" type="file">');
  
});
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Напутал, но не с классами, а с наследованностью. Форма всплывала в поп-апе, и на местах инпута поверх - как бы оказывалась подложка поп-апа, по которой закрывается поп-ап.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была не в jQuery и не в input'e, а копипасте чужого кода.
Надо внимательнее смотреть наследование при определении click...
Получалось так, что при click на input - выполнялось действие родительского элемента, у которого `if(e.target == this){ e.preventDefault(); }`

Спасибо всем кто подключился.